# Acoplamiento de backgroundcolors CSS en gridview

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

tengo un problema con mi GridView.
Se están acoplando las propiedades Background color en los tags .
Necesito que se muestre el elemento que posea el tag "selectedRow".

Al hacer click sobre un elemento de la grilla, se setean los atributos de la siguiente forma, para el seleccionado:

`gvTickets.SelectedRow.CssClass = "DataGridViewCP selectedRow standardBorder";`

Para las otras filas:
 `dgvTickets.SelectedRow.CssClass = "DataGridViewCP row standardBorder";`

Ahora usando el f12 me encuentro con los tags TR de la siguiente forma:

`<TR class="DataGridViewCP selectedRow standardBorder" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: white"></TR>`

`<TR class="DataGridViewCP row standardBorder" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: white"></TR>`

Agrego una foto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito de alguna forma que el css selectedRow se visualice por encima del backgroundcolor white estilo alineado.
Cualquier mano es de gran ayuda, gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! supongo es asp.net no?

Comment: si, es asp.net!